# Regression or Classification?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

When using a neural network to predict the error percentage of a manufacturing process, where there are some inputs into the process out of our control (random) is it best to use regression or classification?

Example,

An output can be error rates ranging from -900% to +900% with the average & median error being 9% (Its a fat tailed bell curve). Should we use regression and attempt to predict the error amount or classify errors into sigmas from the median, for example 900% is 5 Sigmas from the median. We would therefore have 11 categories -5 to +5

Comment: Probably regression, you can divide the range into "classes" later if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output depends on your use case, far more than on the data.  Once this model is trained, you will use it by giving it an input vector, one series of inputs.  Your model will produce an output number.  What do you plan to do with this output number?  For sake of argument, let's consider two similar predictions part-way up the positive side.

Your outputs are either +2, +2 (classification) or +350%, +380% (regression).

Do you need to react to the two outputs identically?  Does everything at roughly +2 receive the same treatment -- if so, you have a clear case for classification -- or are there slight differences based on the relative magnitude -- suggesting a regression model.

Also, what model types are you considering?  If you've already chosen a relatively simple ANN, then you may as well make it a regression model and get the additional "accuracy" in the prediction.  If you find an advantage to certain non-linear functions, or the simplicity of categories (as opposed to experimenting with various non-linear terms for your regression equation), then use the classification method.

Comment: Thanks, these questions helped me make an informed decision. In the end Regression made the most sense, the combo of models most suited regression and the variance in the data, which is input to their process meant classification would end up with far too many categories to be meaningful